# Clearing multiple filtered columns using SpecialCells(x1CellTypeVisible)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a macro I set up which filters on column K and clears a second column e.g. column AA for these filtered amounts.

```
Range("AA5", Range("AA5").End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).ClearContents
```

I have two questions:

1. Main question - how do I now update to include multiple columns which are not connected from row 5 downwards, e.g. AJ, AS, BB etc.?
2. Assuming my headers are in Row 4, will the above cause any issues when filtering for rows starting only after row 5, or is there any better practice?

I'm OK reading code from my college computing days, but bear in mind I'm not a techy person

A problem I had when simply having multiple lines of the same code was that it would be dynamic and therefore would remove some rows from the filter in column K once for example column AA was cleared, and thereby not clearing all the relevant cells in AJ or AS.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account that you will be clearing all visible cells in every 9th column, from row 5 to the last used row in the column, then this macro should work.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3") 'change the sheet name as required

    'For loop to start at col AA and loop to the last column, jumping to every 9th column
    For i = 27 To .Cells(5, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column Step 9

        'set the range from row 5 to the last row and clear visible cell in the column
        .Range(.Cells(5, i), .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).ClearContents

    Next i 'loop to the next column

End With
```